# Возможно ли изменить внешний вид кнопок социальных сетей от Яндекса?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Назрел такой вопрос, возможно, когда-то давно он уже поднимался. Однако подобного поста я не увидел.

Дело в том, что у сайта своеобразный дизайн и кнопки соцсетей в нем уже прорисованы. Не так давно заказчик научился пользоваться метрикой и изъявил желание видеть количество кликов по кнопкам. Но дизайн кнопок, предлагаемый яндекс сервисом, его не устраивает. Дизайн менять отказывается.

Есть ли варианты изменения внешнего вида кнопок, и если есть, то как это сделать? На установленные кнопки был написан свой скрипт.

Comment: @LuckyMen, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

По идее, картинки должны меняться через скрипт, но у меня почему-то не вышло, может быть, это и нельзя сделать через скрипт, по крайней мере параметров для этого в справке я не нашел.

В общем, дизайн иконок следующим образом изменился через CSS. Рабочий код, но в порядок Вы уж его сами приведите:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//yastatic.net/share/share.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script>
new Ya.share({
    element: 'ya_share1',
        elementStyle: {
            'type': 'icon',
            'border': true,
            'quickServices': ['lj', 'twitter', '|', 'vkontakte']
        },
        link: 'http://www.yandex.com/',
        title: 'Yandex — the best search engine in the universe!',
        popupStyle: {
            blocks: {
                'Поделись-ка!': ['lj', 'twitter', '', 'vkontakte'],
                'Поделись-ка по-другому!': ['lj', 'twitter', 'vkontakte']
            },
            copyPasteField: true
        },
        serviceSpecific: {
            twitter: {
                title: '#Yandex — the best search engine in the universe!',
            } 
    }
     });
</script>

<style>
   .b-share-icon_twitter{
     background: url("https://btcjam.com/assets/twitter-icon-3c01ba90ee4aae97496a7932ff91112e.png");
   }
</style>

<span id="ya_share1">Блок кнопок</span>
```

Для каждой иконки по аналогии создайте CSS правило. Да, обязательно еще раз в  [справку](https://tech.yandex.ru/share/doc/dg/concepts/share-button-ov-docpage/) загляните, чтобы все правильно прописать, и, может быть, я что-то упустил, уж простите, если что. Мое решение не самое лучше, но лучше, чем ничего.

**UPD**

Через CSS можно менять и стандартный блок кнопок, конечно, только другие селекторы, но суть не меняется. Довольно неплохо получается.